# How to make a quit button to return to the SWF

Tags: adobe, flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have co-own a virtual game and in that game there is a mini game and I found out how to load an SWF on top of another SWF but when I press the X(/quit) button in the mini game It just quits the current session and makes you log out and log back in. I want to make it like Club Penguin where it loads a SWF then when you press the X button it returns you to the game rather than just making you re-login.

Im using Actionscript 2.0 BTW.

- And here's the code that is used to load the SWF: 
  myMovieClipInstance.loadMovie("minigame.swf");

Answer (score 1):

You could use myMovieClipInstance.unLoadMovie() and then remove the movieclip either using removeMovieClip() or just move it out of the stage.